Typescript type inference not working as expected
I have two very similar functions but typescript can infer the return value of only one of them:
interface URItoKind<A> {}
type URIS = keyof URItoKind<any>;
type Kind<URI extends URIS, A> = URItoKind<A>[URI];

const URI = "Option";
export type URI = typeof URI;
interface URItoKind<A> {
  readonly [URI]: Option<A>;
}
class Option<A> {
  static of: <A>(a: A) => Option<A>;
}

function test1<F extends URIS, A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<F, B>): Option<B>;

function test2<F extends URIS>(): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<F, B>) => Option<B>;

const func = (x: number) => Option.of(x.toString()); // (x: number) => Option<string>
const r1 = test1(func); // Option<unknown> - Doesn't work
const r2 = test2()(func); // Option<string> - Works Fine

Playground Link
I was hoping somebody could explain to me what's the issue. Is this expected or is it a bug? Is there some kind of workaround to make test1 work without specifying the types manually?

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without distractions like unimplemented functions (you can use declare for that) and declaration merging (unless the question is about such merging) and unused type arguments (Option<A> doesn't depend structurally on A). I'd say you could reduce it down to the code at this playground link at least, without changing anything about the question as asked.  (Presumably your code is the way it is because of the underlying use case you have, but you're not asking about that here)

See prev comment. Furthermore I think you might need to actually add some keys to URItoKind otherwise the most reasonable suggestion here is to just eliminate your F type parameter entirely; it's always going to be just "Option". But, as written, it doesn't seem like F will ever be inferrable from a value of type Kind<F, B>, because F is only encoded indirectly, unless you add it structurally to everything.

The issue here arises from TypeScript’s type inference and how generic functions are resolved in different contexts.
test1
function test1<F extends URIS, A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<F, B>): Option<B>;

When you call test1(func), TypeScript tries to infer the types F, A, and B from func’s type, (x: number) => Option<string>:

Inferring F:
F needs to be a subtype of URIS, which is a key in URItoKind<any>. In this case, TypeScript sees that f returns an Option<string>, so it should infer F as string.

Inferring A:
A is inferred from the type of x, so A is inferred as number.

Inferring B:
This is where the problem occurs. TypeScript needs to match Kind<F, B> to Option<string>. However, without clear guidance (e.g., explicit type annotations), TypeScript might not correctly unify B with string. Instead, it might default to a broader type like unknown.


Resulting Inferred Types

F: string (correctly inferred).
A: number (correctly inferred).
B: unknown (incorrectly inferred).

test 2
function test2<F extends URIS>(): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<F, B>) => Option<B>;

When you call test2()(func), TypeScript infers the types in two stages.
Stage 1: Inferring F in test2

Inferring F:
test2 doesn’t take any parameters that directly affect the inference of F, so TypeScript looks at the context where the returned function is used. When you call test2(), TypeScript only knows that F extends URIS, but it doesn’t know the specific F yet. However, when you later pass func to the returned function, TypeScript can use the type of func to infer F.


Stage 2: Inferring A and B in the Inner Function

Inferring A:
A is inferred from the type of the argument x in func, so A is inferred as number.

Inferring B:
B is inferred from the return type of func, which is Option<string>. Since F has been inferred as string (from the context of Kind<F, B>), TypeScript correctly matches B with string.


Resulting Inferred Types

F: string (correctly inferred).
A: number (correctly inferred).
B: string (correctly inferred).

solution
By using Kind<URIS, B> directly, the function now expects f to return a type Kind<URIS, B>, where URIS is a union of all possible URIs (e.g., "Option" in your case). This change makes the inference of B more straightforward because TypeScript can immediately match Kind<URIS, B> to the actual type returned by f (e.g., Option<string>). Since URIS includes "Option", TypeScript can infer B correctly as string without the complication of also needing to determine F.
declare function test1<A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<URIS, B>): Option<B>;
declare function test2(): <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Kind<URIS, B>) => Option<B>;

Now both work as expected:
const func = (x: number) => Option.of(x.toString()); // (x: number) => Option<string>
const r1 = test1(func); // Option<string> - Works Fine
const r2 = test2()(func); // Option<string> - Works Fine


This explanation isn't correct. In test2() inference of F fails.  TypeScript has no ability to defer inference of F until the second call. It has nothing from which to infer F and immediately falls back to the constraint URIS. It absolutely does not "go through all your generic types until it finds the real answer". I don't know if I would use the term "lazy" to describe anything going on here either.

"When you call test2(), TypeScript only knows that F extends URIS, but it doesn’t know the specific F yet. However, when you later pass func to the returned function, TypeScript can use the type of func to infer F." This is still untrue. When you call test2(), F is immediately resolved to its constraint because inference fails. It does not wait until you call the returned function. TS simply does not work this way.
